# How do i remove images that are dragged onto an object?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, image, uv-image-editor

at the moment i am modeling a Honda s2000 and setting up a render for it. However, i have accidentally dragged a blueprint of the car onto one of the pieces of the car and i don't know how to remove it. I cannot find it in the node editor or in the uv/image editor. Thank you to anyone who helps :D. This is the picture of my car's handle piece and you can see the blueprint printed over my carbon fibre material:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry guys i found it, if anyone has the same issue just go over to the textures tab and delete the dragged image!